# how to fetch data from XML and update database table

Tags: xml, sql-server-2005

I am passing serialized collection(XML) to stored procedure. My XML structure is-

```
<ArrayofDepartmentEntity>
  <Department>
    <id>1004</id>
    <budget>2500.oo</budget>
  </Department>
  <Department>
    <id>1080</id>
    <budget>3500.oo</budget>
  </Department>
  <Department>
    <id>1029</id>
    <budget>4500.00</budget>
  </Department>
</ArrayofDepartmentEntity>
```

**How can I UPDATE corresponding budget column where department IDs are in above XML??** can any body write down the sql syntax.

my SP syntax-

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_SaveDepartentBudget] (                  
@departmentBudgetXML ntext = NULL                  
)                          
AS                        
BEGIN 
DECLARE @ptrHandle int     
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @ptrHandle OUTPUT, @departmentBudgetXML
....Here I want to update Budget foreach departmentID in @departmentBudgetXML
```

Comment: If it's XML - then why do you make your stored proc parameter an `NTEXT` ?? `NTEXT` is deprecated - don't use it anymore! Use `NVARCHAR(MAX)` instead. And if it's XML - use `XML` !

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
DECLARE @XMLString XML
SET @XMLString = '<ArrayofDepartmentEntity>
  <Department>
    <id>1004</id>
    <budget>2500.oo</budget>
  </Department>
  <Department>
    <id>1080</id>
    <budget>3500.oo</budget>
  </Department>
  <Department>
    <id>1029</id>
    <budget>4500.00</budget>
  </Department>
</ArrayofDepartmentEntity>'
SELECT
Department.col.value('id[1]','VARCHAR(20)')AS Id,
Department.col.value('budget[1]','VARCHAR(20)')AS Budget
FROM @XMLString.nodes('//Department') Department(col)
```

**EDIT** : Here is the code to Update

```
UPDATE tblInfo SET Budget = Department.col.value('budget[1]','MONEY')
FROM @XMLString.nodes('//Department') Department(col)
WHERE tblInfo.Id = Department.col.value('id[1]','INT')
```

Comment: it is returning a table of column id and budget. I have tried this before but how to Create Update query foreach `id`. `Update tblBudget SET Budget=budget[1] WHERE Depid = id[1]` something like this.

Comment: For performance reason, try to avoid `.nodes('//Department')` - this is the worst possible XPath.... use  `.nodes('/ArrayofDepartmentEntity/Department')` instead - much faster!

Comment: @ppp: I am not sure there is a direct way to do this, but you can do an select into statement and update the contents to your table. @marc_s: Thank you for sharing :)